# What is web development software for Windows that freeware?

Tags: windows, web, development-environment

I'm new in a web development , i need more more information about a software that i can use it free. I'm using Windows. What web development software i can use for free ?

Comment: I like Netbeans. There area a bunch of free IDE's you can use. Netbeans has a lot of nice integration such as SVN and LESS/SASS compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to develop web application using Microsoft  technologies then you can use Visual studio express edition. These are free and there are tons of free tutorial online that will guide you through step by step.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms